# Lose Filter when Sorting a Gridview

Tags: vb.net, gridview

I can filter my Gridview with a text box however when I click on a column to sort it the filter is lost. I am assuming that I need to add something into my SQL to handle this.

The below is the SQLdataSource for the DataGrid which links to it. What I need to then add in is a variable datafield and keep the search value.

I can get a search value with a session when I do a search but unsure what I need to do to make the other part work.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server"
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:mySQLConnectionString %>"
        DeleteCommand='DELETE FROM [xxx] WHERE ID = @ID'
        ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:mySQLConnectionString.ProviderName %>"
        SelectCommand='spFilterSearchModule'
        SelectCommandType='StoredProcedure'
        >

    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I am therefor looking to get two parts of information

1) What do need to do to filter when you click on a column on the datagrid
2) Where do I put it i.e. page Load etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add:
 FilterExpression="filterfield='expression'"

relpace filterfield with the field you want to filter and change expression to what you want to filter from the field